# Show JQuery UI datepicker on input field click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, focus, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

OK maybe this is a trivial issue but I'm very interested to see if anyone has any ideas on this:

I am using JQuery UI. I have an `<input id="#myfield" type="text">` field and I call `$('#myfield').datepicker()`. The datepicker shows whenever the field gets focus. But the field is the first one in my form and is already in focus when it loads, so clicking on the field doesn't show it. Also, if I close the datepicker with the Esc key, then I can't open it again by clicking on the field, for the same reason: it's already in focus.

I am aware that I could set the parameter `.datepicker({showOn: 'button'})` but I don't want the button. Is there any way to have the datepicker appear when the field gets focus OR is clicked when already in focus? I already tried `$('#myfield').click( function () { $(this).focus() } )` and it makes the datepicker open correctly when I click the input field, but then when I select a date it doesn't appear in the field.

Comment: I quite like the button, its pretty normal to use it, in fact I would say its bad decision to not use it.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you. See my comment below Rohan Büchner's answer on why I don't want the button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#date1').datepicker();

$('#date1').focus(function(){
    $('#date1').datepicker('show');
});

$('#date1').click(function(){
    $('#date1').datepicker('show');
});
//$('#ui-datepicker-div').show();
$('#date1').datepicker('show');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="date1" id='date1'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess opening the datepicker at startup does make sense and it does solve half the problem. It doesn't solve the problem of how to re-open the datepicker by clicking the field after pressing the Esc key, but I'd better get to solving actual bugs instead of playing with trivial issues :)

Comment: @RajanRawal : Thanks Buddy for the answers, i was banging my head from last 3days

Comment: @Ashley I dont know what exactly your use is, but consider to use Bootstrap date picker now and ensure that does not conflict with jquery ui datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

This prob wont answer your question, but could be a work around, if your issue of not having the date picker button, is related to having the date picker button... if that makes any sense?

I had an issue where i didn't want to have the button because of users tabbing through my form/page, and I didn't want the button to have focus. (Weird UI experience)

If that's your case as well... you can always just remove its focus by doing the following.. (It'll also indirectly solve the problem you're having now.)

```
$('#field').datepicker({
      showOn: 'button',
      buttonImage: "/image_path/image.png",
 }).next('img.ui-datepicker-trigger').attr('tabIndex', "-1");
```

Comment: Thanks that's clever. Actually the reason I don't want the button is for consistency. In my app I also have a jqGrid with date columns, where a button would look ugly and would take up precious screen width, so I want my date fields out of the grid to be similar to the  fields inside the grid. I'm upvoting your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario: First field on the page an it should loads closed, without the button, and be opened only on user click. But it was in a closed 'searchbar' component, so changing the default behavior wasn't an option. Here's my workaround:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //getting the controls on the form context
        var calendarios = $('.calendarBox', "#frmOccurrencesHistory");
        //set an invalid option - avoid open on focus and show the buttons
        calendarios.datepicker("option", "showOn", "click");
        //handle click button
        calendarios.each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                $(this).datepicker('show');
            });
        });
    });
```

Not pretty, not perfect, there´s a flash of the calendar when pages load, but that's how far I've come

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat:'dd/M/yy',
   minDate: 'now',
   changeMonth:true,
   changeYear:true,
   showOn: "focus",
   //buttonImage: "YourImage",
   buttonImageOnly: true, 
   yearRange: "-100:+0",  
}); 

  $( "datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```